# GeekBrains вопросы - Входное тестирование

Tags: php, java, c#

Выберите верные синтаксические особенности языков программирования:

a.  { … } - используется для блоков в языках С, С++, Objective-C, Go, Java, JavaScript/ECMAScript, C#, D, Perl, PHP, Ruby, Rust, Scala, S-Lang, Swift, AutoHotkey

b.  *Терминатор точка с запятой используется в PHP*

c.  *from module import function - используется для импорта процедур в Python*

d.  *import package. - используется для импорта пакетов в Java, Kotlin и JavaScript*

e.  обратная косая черта как последний символ строки используется в Java

f.  запятая как последний символ строки используется в Ruby

Ребята, кто знает правильный ответ, подскажите пожалуйста. Голову сломал, почему GeekBrains не принимает этот ответ. Правильный выбрал b,c,d. В чем я не прав?

Comment: Задайте вопрос вашему куратору

Comment: Это тестирования для получения бесплатных курсов.  Я вроде бы правильно отвечаю на этот вопрос. Но почему-то не принимает ответ.

Comment: Вопрос явно на умение гуглить

Comment: `import package.` -- потерялась звёздочка при форматировании текста?  должно быть `import package.*;` или `import package.ClassName;`

Comment: @NowhereMan да при форматировании потерялась. В ответе 'import package.* - используется для импорта пакетов в Java, Kotlin и JavaScript'
Вопрос то простой, гуглиться элементарно.  Но я уже понял, что вопросы составляют бездари. Это уже не первый вопрос с багом.  Отвечаешь верно, а GeekBrains отмечает ответ как неверный. Таких вопросов я уже нашел 2.